# Why this login template is not being displayed properly?

Tags: html, css

I found a nice login form and I wanted to implement it on my project but it doesn't display properly.
this is the original one: https://codepen.io/hugo/pen/ypcqb
and this mine: https://jsfiddle.net/burimsyla/2sex8whj/7/

What am I missing here?

P.S: I included this jquery file: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js.

The code below is also included in the codepan but SO doesn't allow me to post without any code:

```
    <div id="logo"> 
  <h1><i> STARK INDUSTRIES</i></h1>
</div> 
<section class="stark-login">
  
  <form action="" method="">    
    <div id="fade-box">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          
          <button>Log In</button> 
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="hexagons">
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <span>&#x2B22;</span>
        <br>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <span>&#x2B22;</span>
          <br>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span> 
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            <span>&#x2B22;</span>
            
            <br>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              <br>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
                <span>&#x2B22;</span>
              </div>      
            </section> 
            
            <div id="circle1">
              <div id="inner-cirlce1">
                <h2> </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <ul>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **non complied** version of `CSS` thats why your template is breaking on `JS fiddle`.

You need to add a `compiled` version from codepen to be able to get the expected results.

**Live Working Code Demo:**

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700italic";
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400";
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: #000;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}


/* =========================================
Stark Industries Logo
========================================= */

#logo {
  animation: logo-entry 4s ease-in;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 40;
}

h1 {
  animation: text-glow 2s ease-out infinite alternate;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  color: #00a4a2;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000, 0 0 20px #000, 0 0 30px #000, 0 0 40px #000, 0 0 50px #000, 0 0 60px #000, 0 0 70px #000;
  top: 50px;
}

h1:before {
  animation: before-glow 2s ease-out infinite alternate;
  border-left: 535px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00a4a2;
  content: ' ';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -74px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 0;
}

h1:after {
  animation: after-glow 2s ease-out infinite alternate;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-top: 16px solid #00a4a2;
  content: ' ';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -85px;
  top: 24px;
  transform: rotate(-47deg);
  width: 0;
}


/* =========================================
Log in form
========================================= */

#fade-box {
  animation: input-entry 3s ease-in;
  z-index: 4;
}

.stark-login form {
  animation: form-entry 3s ease-in-out;
  background: #111;
  background: linear-gradient(#004746, #111111);
  border: 6px solid #00a4a2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #00fffd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 500px;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.stark-login form:hover {
  border: 6px solid #00fffd;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px #00fffd;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.stark-login input {
  background: #222;
  background: linear-gradient(#333333, #222222);
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
  color: #888;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  width: 400px;
}

.stark-login input:focus {
  animation: box-glow 1s ease-out infinite alternate;
  background: #0B4252;
  background: linear-gradient(#333933, #222922);
  border-color: #00fffc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.1), 0 2px 0 #000;
  color: #efe;
  outline: none;
}

.stark-login input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 2px 0 #000;
}

.stark-login button {
  animation: input-entry 3s ease-in;
  background: #222;
  background: linear-gradient(#333333, #222222);
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Cabin', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  width: 400px;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.stark-login button:hover,
.stark-login button:focus {
  background: #0C6125;
  background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
  color: #00fffc;
  outline: none;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.stark-login button:active {
  background: #292929;
  background: linear-gradient(#393939, #292929);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, inset 1px 0 1px #222;
  top: 1px;
}


/* =========================================
Spinner
========================================= */

#circle1 {
  animation: circle1 4s linear infinite, circle-entry 6s ease-in-out;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #00a4a2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px black, 0 0 0 6px #00fffc;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: -3;
}

#inner-cirlce1 {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 36px solid #00fffc;
  height: 460px;
  width: 460px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#inner-cirlce1:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 240px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#inner-cirlce1:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 480px;
  height: 240px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* =========================================
Hexagon Mesh
========================================= */

.hexagons {
  animation: logo-entry 4s ease-in;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-size: 5.1rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.2em;
  line-height: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px #00fffc;
  top: 310px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(60deg) scale(1.4);
  z-index: -3;
}


/* =========================================
Animation Keyframes
========================================= */

@keyframes logo-entry {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes circle-entry {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
}

@keyframes input-entry {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes form-entry {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    border: 1px solid #00a4a2;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  40% {
    width: 0;
    height: 220px;
    border: 6px solid #00a4a2;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 220px;
    width: 500px;
  }
}

@keyframes box-glow {
  0% {
    border-color: #00b8b6;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.2), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.1), 0 2px 0 #000;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: #00fffc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.6), inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.4), 0 2px 0 #000;
  }
}

@keyframes text-glow {
  0% {
    color: #00a4a2;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000, 0 0 20px #000, 0 0 30px #000, 0 0 40px #000, 0 0 50px #000, 0 0 60px #000, 0 0 70px #000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #00fffc;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.6), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 255, 253, 0.4), 0 2px 0 #000;
  }
}

@keyframes before-glow {
  0% {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #00a4a2;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #00fffc;
  }
}

@keyframes after-glow {
  0% {
    border-top: 16px solid #00a4a2;
  }
  100% {
    border-top: 16px solid #00fffc;
  }
}

@keyframes circle1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <h1><i> STARK INDUSTRIES</i></h1>
</div>
<section class="stark-login">

  <form action="" method="">
    <div id="fade-box">
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required>

      <button>Log In</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="hexagons">
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <br>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <br>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>

    <br>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <br>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
    <span>&#x2B22;</span>
  </div>
</section>

<div id="circle1">
  <div id="inner-cirlce1">
    <h2> </h2>
  </div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

[**Here is how to get complied version of CSS from codepen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4X7m.png)

Comment: @dontdownvoteme you need to click 'Run Snippet' and then click `full page` too see it working. OR JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wfszr8jL/

Comment: I tried to see it in full page and it looks almost good now but still the loader is going behind the login view and it doesn't display correctly

Comment: @dontdownvoteme Check now - i have updated the answer :)

Comment: thanks now it works! However, I might misunderstood you, if I want to implement this in my website, do I need to import something from codepan?

Comment: @dontdownvoteme no you do not need to import anything - you just need to add the complied [CSS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4X7m.png) from codepen and it will work perfectly. Please accept and upvote the answer if i have solved the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221451/discussion-between-alwayshelping-and-dontdownvoteme).

Comment: any idea if its possible to open that form with animation from a js function? Like clicking in on a button and then open the form.

Comment: @dontdownvoteme sure, yes it’s possible but there will be a lot of functionally change required since the whole current code is written in only CSS. So that it can be converted into a JS version to be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

hope you doing good.
First, convert all your links of CSS or js files to the laravel template format.
put all your to public assets folder of laravel directory then chnade all URL direstory in code with this:
{{URL::to('')}}/public/assets/same url that is in code